# Find a sequence of events $A_n$ for which all three inequalities...

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega,F,P)$ denote the probability triple for the discrete uniform distribution on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Find a sequence of events $\{A_n\}$ for which these inequalities hold:

(i) For each sequence $\{A_n\}$,

$$P(\liminf A_n)\leq\inf P(A_n)\leq\limsup P(A_n)\leq P(\limsup A_n)$$

(ii) If $A_n\to A$, then $P(A_n)\to P(A)$

Thus far my logic is as follows: If we take $A_n$ to be the set of even numbers, then for ii) $A_n\to\{2,4\}$, and $P(A_n)\to P(A)=1/2$.

and for i)

$$P\left(\bigcup\bigcap A_k\right) \leq \inf P(A_n) \leq \sup P(A_n) \leq P\left(\bigcap\bigcup A_k\right)$$

I guess I'm having trouble with the concepts of what it means for  $A_n$ to happen infinitely often or almost always. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I changed {$A_n$} to $\{A_n\}$ and P($\bigcup$$\bigcap$$A_k$)$\leq$infP($A_n$)$\leq$limsupP($A_n$)$\leq$P($\bigcap$$\bigcup$$A_k$) to $\displaystyle P\left(\bigcup\bigcap A_k\right) \leq \inf P(A_n) \leq \limsup P(A_n) \leq P\left(\bigcap\bigcup A_k\right)$, etc. It is not proper MathJax usage to keep alternating in and out of MathJax within an expression like that. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

(ii) suggests your sequence $\{A_n\}$ should be monotonic.

If we define $A_n:=\{2,4\}$, then the sequence is comprised of independent events with the same probability, hence $\inf P(A_n)=\sup P(A_n)$, so the middle inequality is satisfied.

Now to the outer inequalities.

The $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ are *tail events*, so we need to define them on the sample space of an infinite sequence of events, which is the Cartesian product of the individual sample spaces:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\Omega^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^n \Omega_i$$

(E.g., like with infinite sequence of coin tosses). Then the sample points in $\omega \in\Omega^{\infty}$ are not individual outcomes, but an *entire sequence* of outcomes. We need to determine:

$$P(\omega \in \Omega^{\infty}: \omega \in \lim \sup A_n)$$

and

$$P(\omega \in \Omega^{\infty}: \omega \in \lim \inf A_n)$$

By the [Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result), **if our events are independent** (and they are for your $A_n$):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P(A_i)=\infty \implies P(\lim \sup A_n)=1$$

Here, $P(A_n)=\frac{1}{2}\;\forall n$ therefore $P(\lim \sup A_n)=1$

This takes care of the RHS.

Now the LHS:

Lets fix an integer $k$, and let $B_k:=\bigcap_{i=k}^{\infty} A_i$, then we know by independence of the $A_i$:

$$P\left(B_k\right)=0$$

However, by definition of $B_k$ we know that $B_1\supset B_2 \supset B_3 \supset....\supset B_n$ therefore,

$$P(B_i)=0,\forall i \implies P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i\right)=P(\lim \inf A_n)\leq \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} P(B_j)=0$$

Thus:

$$0\leq \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2} \leq 1$$